# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: javascript

estou com um problema nesse trecho do código e não consigo solucionar de jeito nenhum, toda vez que eu executo o código e faça a busca (Auto Complete de Palavras) , ele retorna o erro Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined.

Já verifiquei aqui e ele está chamando o json, fazendo o mapeamento certinho, o problema mesmo está nesse macth, alguém poderia me ajudar com isso, por gentileza?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

Código com erro abaixo:

```
function findMatches(wordToMatch, brands) {
  return brands.filter(place => {

    const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
    return place.codebrand.match(regex) || place.labelbrand.match(regex)
  });
}


function displayMatches() {
  const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, brands);
  const html = matchArray.map(place => {
    const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
    const codebrandName = place.codebrand.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
    const labelbrandName = place.labelbrand.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
    return `
      <li>
        <span class="name"> Código: "${codebrandName}", Marca: ${labelbrandName}</span>

      </li>
    `;
  }).join('');
  suggestions.innerHTML = html;
}
```

ou
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que seria esse `this.value`? Me parece que não se refere a nada.

Comment: `return place.codebrand.match` - `codebrand` não terá a propriedade `match` definida. Isso é facil de confirmar fazendo antes dessa linha `console.log(place.codebrand);`

Comment: @dvd eu peguei esse código de outro projeto e fiz uma nova adaptação, praticamente eu só alterei os valores do json e as informações do match. Pelo que eu vi aqui o problema mesmo é com esse match, só que não sei como solucionar :(

Comment: @Isac eu não compreendi bem a sua resposta, você poderia me dizer qual o caminho para solucionar isso? valeu

Comment: Certamente que não consigo dizer pois não sei de onde vem esse `place.codebrand` nem como foi construido. Melhor será tentar reproduzir um exemplo funcional na pergunta, ou mostrar como vieram essas partes do código.

Comment: Ele vem de um json, exemplo:

  {
            "codebrand": "6927",
            "labelbrand": ""marca2""
        },
        {
            "codebrand": "6921",
            "labelbrand": "marca2"
        },

Comment: Coloque um `console.log(place.codebrand);` no início da função `function findMatches(wordToMatch, brands) {` e veja o que mostra.

Comment: Nesse exemplo de json que deu, `codebrand` é um numero em forma de `string` e não tem nenhuma propriedade `match`.

Comment: Ele apresenta o seguinte erro > 

console.log(place.codebrand);
VM158:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: place is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13